# Adapting UCI Lisp loop to common lisp

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

Hi I'm adapting the following UCI lisp code to common lisp.

This is the original function:

```
(DE MATCH-ARGS (PAT-ARGS CONST BINDING-FORM)
  (LOOP ((INITIAL PAT-ARG NIL CONST-VAL NIL)
         (WHILE (SETQ PAT-ARG (POP PAT-ARGS)))
         (DO (SETQ CONST-VAL (FILLER:ROLE (ROLE:PAIR PAT-ARG) CONST)))
         (WHILE (SETQ BINDING-FORM
                      (MATCH (FILLER:PAIR PAT-ARG)
                             CONST-VAL
                             BINDING-FORM)))
         (RESULT BINDING-FORM]
```

Here's my current adaptation of it:

```
(defun match-args  (pat-args const binding-form)
    (loop (initial pat-arg nil const-val nil)
          (while (setq pat-arg (pop pat-args)))
          do (setq const-val (filler/role (role/pair pat-arg) const))
          (while (setq binding-form
                    (match (filler/pair pat-arg)
                           const-val
                           binding-form)))
          (result binding-form)))
```

Here's the error that it shows:

```
*** - LOOP: illegal syntax near (INITIAL PAT-ARG NIL CONST-VAL NIL) in
       (LOOP (INITIAL PAT-ARG NIL CONST-VAL NIL) (WHILE (SETQ PAT-ARG (POP PAT-ARGS))) DO
        (SETQ CONST-VAL (FILLER/ROLE (ROLE/PAIR PAT-ARG) CONST))
        (WHILE (SETQ BINDING-FORM (MATCH (FILLER/PAIR PAT-ARG) CONST-VAL BINDING-FORM)))
        (RESULT BINDING-FORM))
```

Please help. Match, filler/role, filler/pair and role/pair are all custom functions.

Answer (score 0):

i would say it'd look something like this:

```
(defun match-args (pat-args const binding-form)
  (loop for pat-arg in pat-args
        for const-val = (filler/role (role/pair pat-arg) const)
        do (setq binding-form
                 (match (filler/pair pat-arg)
                   const-val
                   binding-form))
        while binding-form
        collect binding-form))
```

it would be better if you could show the source of those functions (or at least their protocol), and input parameters example.